# Passing the output of a React component as props

Tags: reactjs

React newbie here.

I am trying to pass component ref (component A) into another component (component B) so that I can get the inner HTML of the component.

I have tried the code below, but the ref just appears to be empty (I think this is because it hasn't actually rendered yet).

Am I doing this correctly?

Component A:

```
export default function SendOrPrintInvoice(props) {
  var layoutRef = useRef();
  var emails = ["test@test.com"];
  return(
    <Layout ref={layoutRef}/>
    <SendEmailModal list={emails} layoutRef={layoutRef}/>
  );
}
```

Component B:

```
export default function EmailInvoiceModal(props) {
  console.log("Got email addresses: "+JSON.stringify(props.list);
  console.log("Got layoutRef: "+JSON.stringify(layoutRef);
}
```

Comment: No, that's not how component refs work, and passing around refs is probably not something you should do until you really understand what you're doing (forwardRef + useImperativeHandle). Instead, you should think more about how to structure your app-- props are meant to be passed from parent to child, not laterally. You need to think about which information should be encapsulated in which component.

Comment: OK, thank you. That makes sense. I think I've made the mistake before of trying to pass things laterally.